# Does assert_not_nil foo == assert defined? foo in Ruby's Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, assertion, testunit

I'm new to Ruby/Rails testing. It seems the Test::Unit method `assert_not_nil foo` is true just in case `foo` is defined (i.e., it is not `nil`). Right?

So is `assert_not_nil foo` equivalent to `assert defined? foo`?

If not, how do they differ? If so, is there any reason why I would want to prefer one of these over the other?

Maybe more generally, it seems like `assert` can be combined with other expressions in place of more specialized assertion methods like `assert_equal` and `assert_not` etc. But it seems that the specialized methods are more standard practice. Is that right? Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nil` is a value, so a variable who's value is nil is defined. Here's some repl output to demonstrate:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = nil
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> defined? a
=> "local-variable"
[3] pry(main)> defined? b
=> nil
```

You may be confused because accessing an undefined instance variable also returns `nil`, but that's still not the same:

```
[4] pry(main)> defined? @b
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> @b = nil
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> defined? @b
=> "instance-variable"
```

Global variables (`$foo`) work like instance variables in this respect, but accessing an uninitialized class variable (`@@bar`) raises `NameError`.

One last thing: local variables are declared at parse time in Ruby, so if any branch of your method sets a local, that local is defined (and initialized to `nil`) anywhere in the method (or block).

Comment: So if `foo = nil` then `assert_not_nil foo` is `false` while `assert defined? foo` is `true`. Right?